# connecting monitor to docking station

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, docking-station

I recently got one of these docking stations (http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00FIKV524/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). It all works perfectly (keyboard, mouse, speakers, printer), apart from the monitor.

I have a Samsung  S24C300HS (http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00CDP6JBE/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). The monitor works fine when I connect it directly to my laptop (a Toshiba Sattelite Pro C50-A-137, btw) either via VGA or HDMI, but not when it is connected to the docking station. Neither VGA nor HDMI work.

Not sure I'm doing something wrong, but checked on internet forums and installation videos and it all seems to be connected as it should. I wonder if the product might be faulty?